# jersey post xml file

Tags: java, xml, post, jersey

I want to post a xml file to my server, then I prase the file.

here is my html file:

```
<form action="rest/installationService/postInstallationTasks" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm">
    <input type="file" id = "uploadFile" name="filename" class="fileUpload" multiple>
    <div style="float: right">
        <button id="px-submit" type="submit"  >upload</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

here is installation.xml

```
<installations>
  <installation>
    <address>湖北省武汉市武昌区华城广场1号</address>
    <customerId>0</customerId>
    <id>2</id>
    <isComplete>0</isComplete>
    <postDate>2014-10-31T00:00:00+08:00</postDate>
    <uploadFlag>0</uploadFlag>
    <username>root</username>
  </installation>
  <installation>
    <address>湖北省武汉市武昌区华城广场2号</address>
    <customerId>0</customerId>
    <id>4</id>
    <isComplete>0</isComplete>
    <postDate>2014-10-31T00:00:00+08:00</postDate>
    <uploadFlag>0</uploadFlag>
    <username>root</username>
  </installation>
</installations>
```

and there is a Installation class and add @XmlRootElement on it;

how do i write on my server?